# How can I remove the space between fields show in a view that are output with a custom template?

Tags: views, theming

I have a view that has two fields, A and B.  Both of these fields are modified using a `views-view-field--myfield.tpl.php` file.

In my output, I want the fields to be displayed as:

> AB (no space in between the values)

However, no matter what I do, it seems that Views puts a space between the two fields.  I am using an *Unformatted list* and under *Settings* I have unchecked **Add views row classes** as well as **Add striping (odd/even) rows classes**.  This has no effect on the spacing.

Under *Settings* for *Fields*, I have unchecked **Provide default field wrapper elements**.  Again, the spacing remains.

I tried rewriting the results of the fields by inputting `[field_fieldA][field_fieldB]` under **Rewrite the output of this field**, but, while this output is shown in the preview in the Views admin interface, it is overwritten by the `views-view-field--myfield.tpl.php` file for the relevant field.

How can I output two values, both of which are output via template files, without a space between them?

Comment: Have you tried "Remove whitespace" under Rewrite Results?
If checked, all whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the output will be removed.

Comment: @Volker I just tried that but it has no effect.  I think the whitespace I am trying to remove is somehow produced by Views itself.

Comment: Any chance the field is already tied to a css rule? some <p> margin, etc...

Comment: @Volker This is a site I just made a couple hours ago still using the Bartik theme.

Comment: You can definitely do it with rewrite results, but I'm not sure what the problem is you are having with templates when you do that.

Comment: @rooby added more details about the problem with rewriting results.

Comment: @PatrickKenny when you view source the page what do you see? Is A and B on two separate lines or on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a quick View here that had three fields:

```
1.  Node title.
2.  Node type.
3.  Global Custom Text Area
```

I changed the HTML Element and Wrapper HTML Elements to SPANs for the first two fields and also set them both to be excluded from display.

For the Global Custom Text Area, I rewrote its output to be `[title][type]` and got the titles smashed right up next to the node types without a space.

ADDITION:

You could also copy `views-view-field.tpl.php` to `views-view-fields--smashed.tpl.php` (or whatever your Views name is :) and then remove all the whitespace from there, eg, this template looks nice like this:

```
 <?php something ?>
   <?php something else ?>
   <?php something else again ?>
 <?php yadda yadda ?>
```

and each of those lines and indents puts in the whitespace that is causing your grief.

If instead this is saved as

```
 <?php something ?><?php something else ?><?php yadda yadda ?><?php one really big long line of code without any intervening tabs or new lines or spaces ?>
```

and your view will be created with the `<divs>` or `<spans>` smashed right up next to each other in the row.  Then CSS it up the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, this works if you can use the default output of the view.  However, in this case, I am using template files.  If I use `[title]` etc. in a global custom text area, I will get the default views output, not the template file output that I need.

Comment: Grrr.  Hmm.  Not sure what you are doing in your individual field templates, but (almost) every Views template has access to the entire View Object as the `$view` variable, so, you could make a template for a field that crafts what you want from any other field by accessing whatever you need via `$view->result`.

Comment: Using the View Object allowed me to find a solution by simply lining up three `print` statements together.  Many thanks!